# Conversion from varchar to numeric in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table data is stored as `((1000.000) + 200.000) + 1000.00`

Data type of the column is `nvarchar`.

I would like get the output while selecting the table as 2200.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this this...

```
CREATE TABLE table3
(
    formula_id int,
    formula varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO table3 (formula_id, formula)
VALUES
(1, '((1000.000) + 200.000) + 1000.00')

DECLARE @formula varchar(max)
SELECT @formula = formula FROM table3 WHERE formula_id = 1    
DECLARE @query varchar(max) = 'SELECT ' + @formula
EXEC(@query)
```

> Note : The last 4 query must run at the same time, else no result will
>   be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic sql

```
declare @query varchar(max) = 'select ((1000.000) + 200.000) + 1000.00'

exec(@query)
```